# Need to group xsl:for-each-group with Muenchian method

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am not able to retrieve unique list by applying Muenchian method. I am trying to group based on "Series Title" attribute

```
Sample Input XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Distribution>
<ManifestHeader>
    <Assets>
        <Asset>
            <ID>23341528</ID>
            <CreateDate>2008-01-14T17:02:01Z</CreateDate>
            <MetaDatas>
                <MetaData Name="psa.orig.source.showTitle">Green Home 2008</MetaData>
                <MetaData Name="displayRunTime">00:01</MetaData>
                <MetaData Name="Series Title">Desperate Landscapes</MetaData>
            </MetaDatas>
        </Asset>
        <Asset>
            <ID>23341529</ID>
            <CreateDate>2010-08-23T15:44:58Z</CreateDate>
            <MetaDatas>
                <MetaData Name="psa.orig.source.showTitle">Urban Oasis 2010</MetaData>
                <MetaData Name="displayRunTime">00:02</MetaData>
                <MetaData Name="Series Title">Toy Hunter</MetaData>
            </MetaDatas>
        </Asset>
        <Asset>
            <ID>23377202</ID>
            <CreateDate>2007-05-18T07:40:25Z</CreateDate>
            <MetaDatas>
                <MetaData Name="webSeries"/>
                <MetaData Name="psa.orig.source.showTitle">Cool Tools</MetaData>
                <MetaData Name="displayRunTime">00:20</MetaData>
                <MetaData Name="Series Title">Desperate Landscapes</MetaData>
            </MetaDatas>
        </Asset>
    </Assets>
</ManifestHeader>
</Distribution>
```

XLST:

```
<xsl:key name="keySeriesName" match="MetaData[@Name='Series Title']" use="text()" />

<xsl:for-each select="MetaData[@Name='Series Title'][generate-id() =                        
                    generate-id(key('keySeriesName', text())[1])]">
also tried:
<xsl:for-each select="MetaData[@Name='Series Title'][count(. |      key('keySeriesName',text())[1]) = 1]">
```

anyhelp would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since the `<MetaData>` elements are children of `<MetaData>` and you are trying to search across the entire collection of them within the document, you are going to need to adjust your XPath to ensure that you are addressing all of them:

```
/Distribution/ManifestHeader/Assets/Asset/MetaDatas/MetaData
    [@Name='Series Title'][generate-id() =                        
                           generate-id(key('keySeriesName', text())[1])]
```

or you could use the shorter, but less efficient:

```
//MetaData[@Name='Series Title'][generate-id() = 
                                 generate-id(key('keySeriesName', text())[1])]
```